# How does passing input as an argument work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I've been using variables to pass as arguements this entire time, but I came across a solution that uses input and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how it works.

```
def reverse(input=''):
    return input[::-1]
```

What is the point of using input when you could do this?

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
```

They both work exactly the same.
I thought using input would let you enter any string you want but it doesn't.
I got this from Excercism.

Comment: functions are first class objects in python, meaning you can shadow them and re-define them. `input` is not a reserved word or function, and in this case is nothing more significant than a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between those two definitions of `reverse` is that the first gives a default value for the argument. The name of the argument is irrelevant.

With the first definition you could do

```
reverse()
# => ''
```

Calling the second definition with no arguments would cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter names do not matter here. In fact, the first function argument  "shadows"  the `input()` function .

> I thought using input would let you enter any string you want

It does, when *called as a function* **and** no `input` variable is defined already that is not a function that accepts user input.

The true difference here is the default value for the parameter

You're confusing this

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]

print(reverse(input())
```

With this

```
def reverse(input=''):
    return input[::-1]

print(reverse())  
print(reverse(input=input())
```